# convolution converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f\in L^p (\mathbb {R^d}), g\in L^q (\mathbb{R^d})$ and $1=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}, 1<p <\infty $. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f*g(x)=0. $

I guess I can use the uniform continuity and some density argument for $f $. Young's inequality doesn't seem useful. Give me some hint..

Comment: For $p=1$, this is false in general. Take e.g. $g \equiv 1$.

Comment: It's not true for $p=1$,$q=\infty$. If both $p$ and $q$ are finite then yes, approximate both $f$ and $g$ in norm by continuous functions with compact support...

Comment: I omitted the condition. Hmm, then I guess I can prove.. I just used one-sided density arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As pointed out, it's only true for $\infty > p > 1$. For $f,g \in C^{\infty}_c (\mathbb{R}^d)$, the result is straightforward (as the $\text{supp} (f*g) \subset \text{supp} f + \text{supp} g$).

If $f \in C^{\infty}_c$ only, then $ |f * g - f*h| \le \|f\|_p \|g-h\|_q$ by Young's inequality. For suitable $h \in C^{\infty}_c$, by density, then using the former fact we may close this case easily.

It is now straightforward to complete the only case left.